# Time.parse and DateTime.parse returns different results

Tags: ruby, datetime

Why do these two `parse` statements return different results?

```
time = "13:30:0"

DateTime.parse(time).to_time.utc
#=>  2013-10-13 13:30:00 UTC

Time.parse(time).utc
#=>  2013-10-13 11:30:00 UTC
```

Comment: What timezone do You have set in Your configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no timezone information in the input `String`. `DateTime.parse` therefore assumes UTC. `Time.parse` assumes local time, and I guess you're in UTC+2.

```
>> time = "13:30:0"
=> "13:30:0"
>> DateTime.parse(time).to_s
=> "2013-10-13T13:30:00+00:00"
>> Time.parse(time).to_s
=> "2013-10-13 13:30:00 +0200"
```